# why Backdrop filter isn't working correctly flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, filter

I've tried to implement backdrop filter in flutter but It doesn't work.

```
ClipRect(
    child:BackdropFilter(filter:ui.ImageFilter.blur(
    sigmaX: 5.0,
    sigmaY: 5.0,
      ),
     child: Container( 
     child: (Image.file(
     _image,
     height: 400,
     width: 400,
     fit: BoxFit.cover,
               )),
            ),
           ),
         )
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use a stack and place the `ImageFilter` on top of the image you want to blur or you can use the `colorBlendMode:` property instead.

```
Container(
                              child: (Image.file(
                                _file,
                                height: 400,
                                colorBlendMode: BlendMode.overlay,
                                color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
                                width: 400,
                                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                              )),
                            ),
                          ),
```

With stack -

```
          child: ClipRect(
            child: Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                Card(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 20),
                  elevation: 16,
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
                  child: Container(
                    height: 220 * _zoomAnim.value,
                    width: 150,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                        image: DecorationImage(
                            fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
                            image: AssetImage('images/tour$index.jpg'))),
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  height: 220,
                  width: 150,
                  child: BackdropFilter(
                    child: Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.2),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
                    ),
                    filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 1, sigmaY: 0),
                  ),
),)...]))
```

Comment: I've tried your method but it didn't give me the result

Comment: But I haven't try the stack method

Comment: I have edited my answer for implementing Stack @Axen_Rangs

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap them into a stack and set the height for the container behind the image like this:

Note that in the below code I'am blurring the whole screen except for the image.
You can change the size of the blurred part by setting the container's size.

```
    Stack(
     children : [
       BackdropFilter(
              filter: ImageFilter.blur(
                sigmaX: 5.0,
                sigmaY: 5.0,
              ),
              child: Container(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height
                color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.4),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
              child: Center(
                child: ClipRRect(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                  child: Image.file(
                    _image,
                    height: 400,
                    width: 400,
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            )
    ],)
```