# Bokeh Image Filter Effekt in flutter

Tags: image, flutter, filter, bokeh, imagefilter

I guess this isn't easily possible but maybe someone knows how to create a Bokeh image filter effect on flutter images. Maybe there is a package which supports this image filter effect. Or maybe someone knows what I need to create a Bokeh image filter effect?

I'm happy for every help. I hope this question isn't to broad, if it is im sorry...

[image]

Comment: https://medium.com/fluttervn/how-to-make-blur-effect-in-flutter-using-backdropfilter-imagefilter-559ffd8ab73

Comment: hey @anmol.majhail thanks for the link. Im aware of the backdropfilter yet the bokeh image filter effect only blurres the background an leaves the views in the foreground unblurred

Comment: You have to use a stack - Check this answer @ChristianX : (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62387368/why-backdrop-filter-isnt-working-correctly-flutter/62387494?noredirect=1#comment110338372_62387494)

Comment: hmm I see. But what if I want the blur filter to be applied automatically to the background of an image where I have no idea where the background and foreground starts? Then I would need an AI which figures this for me out, would I?